# PDO pivot a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a table with questions and another table with answers like so:

questions

```
eventid    questionid    question
```

answers

```
eventid    questionid   userid   response
```

How do I make select query so that there is 1 row for each unique userid with all their responses in that row with the questions as column headers?

Comment: This is complicated if the exact number of questions and answers (and hence columns) is not known ahead of time. Since you are using PHP, why not just select the rows in a normal 1 row per answer, then format the output the way you want in PHP?  Otherwise, it requires constructing a dynamic SQL statement.

Comment: Oh yeah I guess that would be much simpler

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a way to create a simple SQL statement with a variable number of columns like that. I would just join the two tables and do something like this:

```
$lastUserID = null;
$results = array();
foreach ($statement as $row) {
    if ($row['userid'] != $lastUserID) {
        $lastUserID = $row['userid'];
        $results[$lastUserID] = array();
    }
    $results[$lastUserID][$row['question']] = $row['response'];
}
```

Keep in mind you want to avoid using a nested array data structure like that without adequate documentation in the function comments. You may also wish to create a class of some kind to wrap this $results array (e.g. getUserIDs(), getQuestionToAnswerMapping($userID) or something like that).

Comment: So you would inner join the two tables on the questionid and then use that on it?

Comment: Yep, that would be the plan.