# convert row in database to column in excel

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pivot, phpexcel

I have a survey and I need to convert it to excel

This is my table in database:

| UserId | QuesId | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

I need to pivot the data and fill the excel spreadsheet like this by using PHP class:

| UserId | Answer QuesId1 | Answer QuesId2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |

My code:

```
$ExportSheet2= $Link->prepare("SELECT main_data. UserId, questions.Id, Ans from  main_data, questions WHERE main_data.Id = UserId and questions.Id=QuesId" );

$ExportSheet2->execute();
$ExportSheet2Count=$ExportSheet2->rowCount(); 
if ($ExportSheet2Count > 0) {
    $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
    $sheet2 = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
    $rowCount = 2;
    $column = 1;
    while ($row = $ExportSheet2->fetch()) {
        $InfoID = $row[' UserId '];
        $data[] = $row;// store data in array 
    }
}
$sheet2->SetCellValue('A' . $rowCount, $InfoID); //print user ID
$sheet2->SetCellValue('B' . $rowCount, mb_strtoupper($data[], 'UTF-8')); //Answer QuesId1
$sheet2->SetCellValue('C' . $rowCount, mb_strtoupper($data[], 'UTF-8')); //Answer QuesId2
```

I can not store the answer of question in array and fill the excel.

I can not store data in array then fill it in excel.

Comment: What is it in this Question/Answer ([Using PHPExcel to make automatic generated excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360461/using-phpexcel-to-make-automatic-generated-excel-files))that you cannot do?

Comment: Are you struggling to access array data with specific indexes? `mb_strtoupper($data[0])`

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of questionable syntax and design decisions, so it may be simpler to just recommend a new script.  Your attempt to restructure the result set data isn't implementing a truly dynamic "pivot", so if a user might not have completed all questions, then the output may be skewed or make PHP complain to you about something missing.

I'm not experienced in PHPExcel, but based on [Using PHPExcel to make automatic generated excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11360461/2943403) and [PDO pivot a table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21994890/2943403), there is enough to complete this task.  The following is an untested suggested script.  I did create [a generalized demo that performs a pivot](https://3v4l.org/9qNJV).

1. Fetch the database results:

   ```
   $sql = <<<SQL
       SELECT m.UserId,
              q.Id,
              Ans
       FROM main_data AS m,
       JOIN questions AS q
            ON  m.Id = q.UserId
                AND m.QuesId = q.Id
       ORDER BY q.Id, m.UserId
   SQL;
   $userSubmissions = $link->prepare($sql);
   $userSubmissions->execute();
   $resultSet = $userSubmissions->fetchAll();
   ```
2. Create the sheet, its header row, and the pivot array:

   ```
   if ($resultSet) {
       $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
       $sheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
       $colLetter = 'A';
       $rowNumber = 1;
       $pivot = [];
       $questionIds = [];
       $sheet->SetCellValue("$colLetter$rowNumber", 'UserId');
       foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
           ++$colLetter;
           $questionIds[$row['Id']] = $row['Id'];
           $sheet->SetCellValue("$colLetter$rowNumber", $row['Id']);
           $pivot[$row['UserId']][$row['Id']] = $row['Ans'];
       }
   ```
3. Write the pivoted data into the sheet's rows

   ```
       foreach ($pivot as $userId => $qAndA) {
           $colLetter = 'A';
           ++$rowNumber;
           $sheet->SetCellValue("$colLetter$rowNumber", $userId);
           foreach ($questionIds as $id) {
               ++$colLetter;
               $sheet->SetCellValue("$colLetter$rowNumber", mb_strtoupper($qAndA[$id] ?? '', 'UTF-8'));
           }
       }
   }
   ```